# function not being executed after entering the city name in google Place picker in swift 4

Tags: ios, function, swift4

I have tried several times but no clues. The problem is when city is entered into google place picker for the very first time whole of the retrieved json data for the weather gets printed onto the console (which means that both current weather function and forecast weather function gets called) but when city is entered the second time only current weather data function gets called but forecast weather data function doesn't and the tableView shows data from previous city since forecast weather hasn't executed the second time.

```
// function below calls both functions when user enters city
func userEnteredCity(city: String, placeId: String)
    {
        let parameters :[String:String] = ["q": city, "appid": APP_ID]
        getWeather(weatherUrl: Current_WEATHER_URL, params: parameters)
        weatherForecast(weatherUrl: Forecast_WEATHER_URL, params: parameters)
        loadFirstPhotoForPlace(placeID: placeId)
    }
/* getWeather provides currentWeather and weatherForecast provide forecast data functions have been defined below*/

   func weatherForecast(weatherUrl: String, params: [String:String])
    {
        Alamofire.request(weatherUrl, method: .get, parameters: params).responseJSON
            {
                (response) in
                let result = response.result
                if let dictionary = result.value as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject>
                {
                    if let list = dictionary["list"] as? [Dictionary<String, AnyObject>]
                    {
                        for item in list {
                        print(item)
                        let forecast = ForecastData(weatherDict: item)
                        self.forecastArray.append(forecast)
                        }
                         self.weatherTable.reloadData()
                    }


                }

        }

}
```

Please help me on this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, is the `print` statement being executed and does it print the forecast data for the new city?

If so, please check what your `forecastArray` is intended to provide. Currently, you only seem to add new forecast data to the existing array, e.g. it is never cleared. You should do so before you fetch the data:

```
func weatherForecast(weatherUrl: String, params: [String:String]) {
    self.forecastArray.removeAll()
    Alamofire.request(weatherUrl, method: .get, parameters: params).responseJSON {
        // ... same as before
    }
}
```

Comment: ThankYou for the answer. The code works fine now. I had to clear the array before loading data.